# Como enviar notificaciones push con PHP en iOS y Android

Tags: php

Buenas, estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con PHP y MySQL, y en un futuro me gustaría portar esta aplicación web a iOS y Android.

Lo que no sé es como podría hacer que se envíen notificaciones push al usuario sin tener que desarrollar una aplicación específica para cada dispositivo, y aprovechando la aplicación web que es responsive.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola  Alex bienvenido. Asi no es como funciona este sitio. Por favor, lee el [tour]y [ask] para aprender mas del sitio y como hacer preguntas de calidad. Debes investigar e intentarlo. Esto es muy amplio para que podamos ayudarte